# Using cpulimit on a command rather than a PID

Tags: server, tar, cpulimit

I am trying to use `cpulimit` on a command, like:

```
cpulimit -e 'tar -chzf [...]' -l 50
```

but cpulimit seems not to be able to start the process:

```
Warning: no target process found. Waiting for it...
```

So how do I invoke cpulimit to start `tar` with all it's input arguments?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
cpulimit -l 50 -- tar -chzf ...
```

From the examples in [`man cpulimit`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/cpulimit.1.html#contenttoc3):

```
 # cpulimit -l 20 firefox
        Launch Firefox web browser and limit its CPU usage to 20%

 # cpulimit -l 25 -- firefox -private
        Launch Firefox web browser in private mode and limit its CPU usage to 25%
```